# onResume() Issue after EditText Focus()

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus, onresume

I am using `onResume()` to check if user has pressed Back Button and then take user to at some `fragment`.
It is working fine if Focus is disabled on `EditText`. But, If there is Focus on `EditText` then if user press Back Button, It finish the application.
So, I want to fire `onResume()` and take user to `Home() Fragment` as per code any how whether there is a Focus on EditText or not.
How to prevent this issue ?
**My Code :**

```
etComment.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        etComment.setFocusable(true);
        etComment.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

        return false;
    }
});
```

**onResume() :**

```
@Override
public void onResume() {

    super.onResume();

    getView().setFocusable(true);
    getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    getView().requestFocus();
    getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP
                    && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

                for (int i = 0; i < fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); ++i) {
                    fm.popBackStack();
                }

                fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame, new Home()).commit();

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It's very unclear what your actual issue is..

Comment: I still don't see what you are actually trying to do here. If the app crashes, look at the logcat. Anyway, you do know there's a method for that? I'd handle it from here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed()

Answer (score 1):

Add this code

```
EditText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            EditText.clearFocus();
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think just using `onBackPressed()` with `mPausing` and `mBackPressed` is better.

```
private boolean mPausing = false;
private boolean mBackPressed = false;

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mPausing = true;
}

@Override
protected void onResumeFragments() {
    super.onResumeFragments();
    mPausing = false;
    if (mBackPressed) {
        onBackPressed();
        mBackPressed = false;
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mPausing) {
        mBackPressed = true;
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); ++i) {
        fm.popBackStack();
    }
    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame, new Home()).commit();
}
```

Then you don't have to worry about focus. Is there any reason for using `setFocusable()` method?

Also, this is what I'm using `onResumeFragments()` instead of `onResume()`: [Fragment Transactions & Activity State Loss](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html)

This article says:

> For example, you should not commit transactions inside the FragmentActivity#onResume() method, as there are some cases in which the method can be called before the activity's state has been restored (see the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#onResume()) for more information).